# How to prevent same date number to be parsed in recyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

inside the json there is lot of same date 
i want to take only one date a day like nov-11 ,nov-12,nov-13 
so i can take their data daily not hourly and parse it in recyclerView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WeatherViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String a = forecasts.get(position).dt_txt;
    String aa= a.substring(5,10);
    String b=  Math.round(forecasts.get(position).getMain().temp) + "°C";

    holder.hourlyTxt.setText(aa);
    holder.hourlyTemp.setText(b);
    Picasso.get().
            load(String.format("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/%s.png", forecasts.get(position).getWeatherList().get(0).icon))
            .into(holder.icon);
}
```

this is the json
       https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Comment: find duplicates and remove it

Comment: can you help me with codes

Comment: use hashmap or list of dates and add check if list.contains("1nov") dnt add data

Comment: i want to add it once

Comment: you will get them only once if you use hashMap or list

Comment: should i put the String a inside arraylist ?

Comment: i cant do it any help ?